# angularfire2 firebase config switch dynamically in the ionic app

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I am using angularfire2 in my ionic app following https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/ionic/cli.md

The step 4 and 5 looks like below in my app

```
export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXX.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://XXX.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "XXXX.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: '542659015683'
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage,
    LoginPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
...
```

The above works just fine. However, we want to run the same app in dev or production mode. The difference will be the firebase side configuration.

So, the way to do this is planned using a switch in the app to toggle as dev or production. And on toggling the switch we should be able to re-initialize the firebase config. Which would be basically re-executing below having a different firebaseConfig payload.

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
```

Please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: Since you are going to have many more things different between dev and prod - not just firebase - would you consider doing a cleaner separation than dynamic in app switching (which will be causing issues for sure)

Comment: yes i am thinking that in longer terms but as a shorter term solution due to customer budget we were trying to avoid have standard dev and prod env instances

Comment: Hi, I need to do exactly the same as you, could you tell me if you implement this and how you did it? Thank you.